# Entity Framework: Unable to register the build provider in Web.Config

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework

I am getting this error message when ever I try to update or save my Entity Data Model:

```
ERROR: Unable to register the build provider in Web.Config because of the following exception: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.
```

Then when I try to run the application I get:

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
```

How do I fix it so that it is able to write to the Web.config.  I have been through it with a fine tooth comb but I come up with nothing that is XML broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the following line

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

to

```
<configuration>
```

in your web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what has caused this, it could be that the entity framework files have become corrupt in some way.

The easy way to fix it, is to delete the model remove any reference from the web.config and create the model again using the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was rolling back my code via. SVN.  I didnt take the time to figure out what was exactily wrong.  If it happens again I will post further info.

Answer (score -1):

It wil surely works.

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

to

```
<configuration>
```

Reason of failure was: because of this setting , build provider was not able to register connection string in web.config.